# Setting the height of a table

Tags: html

I would like to set the height of my table so that both tables that are next to each other are the same size I tried vh, %, px I have pt a div around my table, but nothing seems to work.
I also want both tables to be scrollable.
I know there are a lot of nested tables, but that's the obnly way I can get it like I want.

Here is my code:

```css
.tableScroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.tableScroll thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
th {
  background: #eee;     
}
```

```html
<table width='80%' border='10' align='center'>
  <tr>
    <td>Bruto Weight</td>
    <td>10.0000</td>
    <td>Net Weight</td>
    <td>8.0000</td>
    <td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='7'>
      <div height='100px'>
      <table width='100%' border='5'>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='2'>WEEE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='35%' valign='top'>
            <table width='100%' height='100%' border='10'>
              <tr>
                <td>Landen</td>
                <td colspan='2'>
                  <select>
                    <option>België</option>
                    <option>Nederland</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>WEEE</td>
                <td>
                  <div class='tableScroll'>
                    <table width='100%' border='1'>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width='20%'>Recupel 4.3</td>
                        <td width='80%'>Iets me elektriek</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>-></td>
              </tr>
            </table>                    
          </td>
          <td width='65%' valign='top'>
            <div class='tableScroll'>
              <table width='100%' border='1'>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width='5%'>Land</th>
                    <th width='18%'>Code</th>
                    <th width='75%'>Omschrijving</th>
                    <th width='2%'>&nbsp;</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>BE</td>
                    <td>Recupel 4.63</td>
                    <td>Electronische dingens</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>BE</td>
                    <td>Recupel 24.63</td>
                    <td>Electronische dingens</td>
                    <td>X</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    .table-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .table {
        height: 200px;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<div class="table-container">
    <table class="table">
        <!-- table content here -->
    </table>
    <table class="table">
        <!-- table content here -->
    </table>
</div>
```